# How to handle OPTIONS request in nodejs when setting access control in header?

Tags: node.js, next.js, cors

I need to set up a public API endpoint on a server running next.js. The code below works, I get the response without any CORS errors on the client side.

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
  );

  try {
    switch (req.method) {
      case "OPTIONS": {
        res.send(200);
        break;
      }
      case "GET": {
        const response = "data";
        console.log("response in GET:", response);

        if (response != null) {
          res.status(200).json(response);
        }

        res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
        break;
      }
      default: {
        res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

However, I do get an error on the server side:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I'm not sure how to deal with this error, after all the code seems to work.

But what would be the proper way to do this, without getting this error?

Comment: Replace `res.status(200).json(response);` with `return res.status(200).json(response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following code:

```
case "GET": {
    const response = "data";
    console.log("response in GET:", response);

    if (response != null) {
      res.status(200).json(response);
    }

    res.status(500).json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
    break;
  }
```

Here, if `response != null`, it will send the status 200 but then **it will continue** and also send the res.status(500). So it ends up sending 2 responses.

To fix this, replace:

```
if (response != null) {
    res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

with:

```
if (response != null) {
    return res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

The key part here the `return` statement.